# System-wide ShellExecute hooks?

Tags: c++, shellexecute, hook

is there any way I can install a system-wide ShellExecute hook using C++ without having to inject a hooking module into every active process. I am using Windows 7.
My purpose for this is because, I want to be able to select which browser a link is opened in when a link is opened with the default browser using ShellExecute, like this:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "http://stackoverflow.com", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: System wide _means_ in every process. ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter of [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) takes a thread id -- if this is NULL the procedure will be associated with all threads in the same desktop as the calling thread or with a particular thread otherwise.

Read more: [Using Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644960%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This is accepted answer but I still don't see how `SetWindowsHookEx` can hook `ShellExecute`. Nearest thing to this is probably `WH_SHELL` and that too is not supposed to tell if `ShellExecute` has been called.